# Rails 3 Autocomplete - Suggesting Alternatives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm current using Rails 3 autocomplete in an application, but I'd like to know if there is any way to allow the app to make suggestions based on misspelled words.

For example, 'Saving Pirvaet Ryan' would still suggest 'Saving Private Ryan'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you are looking for is a fulltext search. While I personally haven't touched it yet, you might want to check out [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)/[Thinking Sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/), or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)/[Sunspot](http://sunspot.github.com/)

**EDIT** Ok, I read too fast, this doesn't seem to fit what you're asking. Still leaving this here in case it can help anyone.